# Converting from a treeset to abstract list

Tags: java, sorting

I have a class called actionEnt which is an asbtract and it is like the following:

```
public abstract class ActionEnt implements Serializable {

    protected RaceGroup r;
    protected int t1;
    protected int t2;
    protected String name;

    public RaceGroup getRaceGroup() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setRacingTeam(RacingTeam rt) {
        r = rt;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    // return TimeDriver1
    public int getT1() {
        return t1;
    }

    public void setTimeDriver1(int t) {
        t1 = t;
    }

    // return TimeDriver2
    public int getT2() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setT2(int t) {
        t2 = t;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof ActionEnt) {
          ActionEnt other = (ActionEnt) o;
            return this.r.equals(other.r()) && this.name.equals(other.getName());
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

in another class I have a methode that determine which team has won with what time.

in order to make that work I had to convert that list into a treeset list with this methode:

```
  public static TreeSet<Standing> winnerIs(List<ActionEnt> hp) {
    int size = hp.size();
    ArrayList<ActionEnt> listofWinner = new ArrayList<ActionEnt>();
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> timeOfDrivers = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> driverTimes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    TreeSet<Standing> standingSet, treereverse;

    ArrayList<Integer> timeFor = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      driverTimes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      listofWinner.add(hp.get(i));
      String name = hp.get(i).getName();
      map.put(name, Math.max(listofWinner.get(i).getTimeDriver1(), listofWinner.get(i).getTimeDriver2()));
      timeOfDrivers.put(hp.get(i).getTimeDriver1(), hp.get(i).getTimeDriver2());
      driverTimes.add(hp.get(i).getTimeDriver1());
      driverTimes.add(hp.get(i).getTimeDriver2());
      map2.put(hp.get(i).getName(), driverTimes);
    }

    for (ArrayList<Integer> time : map2.values()) {
      timeFor.addAll(time);
    }
    Collections.sort(timeFor);
    Collections.reverse(timeFor);
    standingSet = new TreeSet<Standing>();
    treereverse = new TreeSet<Standing>();

    for (String team : map2.keySet()) {
      standingSet.add(new Standing(team, map2.get(team).get(0)));
      standingSet.add(new Standing(team, map2.get(team).get(1)));
    }
    treereverse = (TreeSet<Standing>) standingSet.descendingSet();
    return treereverse;
  }
```

now that I make the list correctly when I try to make a unittest for this i get the following error:

```
java.util.ArrayList<[team1 -> 37987932, team2 -> 509360, team3 -> 439900, team4 -> 24128, team2 -> 13810, team4 -> 8584, team3 -> 1907, team1 -> 946]> but was:
java.util.ArrayList<[team1 -> 37987932, team2 -> 509360, team3 -> 439900, team4 -> 24128, team2 -> 13810, team4 -> 8584, team3 -> 1907, team1 -> 946]>
```

why is this like this I really cant see the difference!!

Comment: Use the [`addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) method?  Eg `List<ActionEnt> mylist = new ArrayList<>(); mylist.addAll(standingSet);`

Comment: @dsh doesnt work I get this error: The method addAll(Collection<? extends InteractingEntity>) in the type List<InteractingEntity> is not applicable for the arguments (TreeSet<Standing>)

Comment: Note that if you override `equals()`, you also should override `hashCode()`

Comment: Why don't make ActionEnt Comparable? Seems the team with the fastest driver wins, so for each team, the fastest driver is significant => Compare min(t1,t2) of each ActionEnt ... or not?

Comment: Please include your Standing class code.  You will need to write a converter from Standing to ActionEnt.  You might also ask yourself whether there is a simpler solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Fildor that class implements Serializable. and this is how we decode to do it as a group. so I cant just cahnge it on my own!

Comment: Well your group should really review it. As @user7291698 already stated, it should implement `hashCode` to begin with.

Comment: I'd say all you need is a [`TreeMap<int, List<ActionEnt>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) ( List - because there could be a tie )

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Standing> yourSet = ....
List<ActionEnt> yourList = yourSet.stream()
                                  .map(yourTransformationFunction()
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You then only need to supply a function which is capable of transforming your `Standing`-type to your `ActionEnt`-type, e.g.

```
Function<Standing, ActionEnt> yourTransformationFunction() {
  return standing -> {
    // actually do a real transformation here ;-) the following should get you started
    ActionEnt newActionEnt = new ActionEnt(); 
    newActionEnt.set...(standing.get...);
    ...
    return newActionEnt;
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by type?

Comment: yes, I am not sure how to transfer to a different type!

Comment: I expanded the transformation-function a bit. All you have to do is adding the code, which leads from a `Standing` type to an `ActionEnt` type, if that is even possible. You should probably refactor your code, as it looks too complicated for what it is actually doing. Maybe you don't even need a transformation back and forth.

Comment: From my point of view, you wouldn't even need a `Standing` class. ActionEnt has all you need to find an ascending list of times and the according team names ...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the following to make it work:

```
public List<ActionEnt> showWinner(TreeSet<Standing> t) throws IOException {
    (1) List yourList = new ArrayList<ActionEnt>();
    (2) yourList.addAll(t);
    (3) return yourList;
  }
```

it return the correct list with the correct order and the correct type:

how ever I always have this warnings:

```
(1)List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized
(2)Type safety: The method addAll(Collection) belongs to the raw type List. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized
(3)Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<ActionEnt>
```

is this a good fix?

Comment: `List<ActionEnt>` instead of `List` ... ah wait ... this could blow up in your face. You are adding `Standing` instances to a List of `ActionEnt`? How is Standing class related to ActionEnt?

Comment: `addAll` will not work. You need to transform your `Standing` to `ActionEnt` before.